# How open oracle DB Linux (After installation)

Tags: linux, oracle

I have just installed Oracle 11gR2 on my Linux Mint Distro (xfce). All worked fine, and I was able to acces to

```
https://localhost:1158/em [Erreur 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED) ]
```

I rebooted my PC and tried to reopen the page but this time I am unable to open it.

I am not so expert in Linux but could that be a problem of acces permission ?

How could I resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Most likely your oracle daemons were not started automatically after the reboot. Either start them manually or let them run automatically on startup.

Comment: how could I do that ?

Comment: That link points to the Enterprise Manager it does "open" the database. To access the database (e.g. by running SQL statements), use `sqlplus` or any other SQL client

Answer (score 1):

First edit your /etc/oratab changing N to Y like that:

```
orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:N
```

Must be change to Y:

```
orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:Y
```

Then to start you must use the dbstart script like that:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=youroraclehome
su oracle -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart $ORACLE_HOME"
```

Where "oracle" in the "su" command is the name of the user you used to install oracle.

This will up all oracle essential services including the https port 1158 (*and you can put that in an auto-start script*)

And to stop it:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=youroraclehome
su oracle -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbshut $ORACLE_HOME"
```

And to backup it (dump) ;-)

```
export ORACLE_HOME=youroraclehome
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/exp file=mybackup.dmp full=y
```

Remember to test your backup before thinking its working.

Comment: Ups i forget to warn you to edit oratab...

Comment: Thanks, I will check your suggestion and give you a feedback :)

Comment: Where are you? =[ it works?